# I need SSR mode for my entire site, in New .Net 8 Blazor server but my layout page isn't upgraded in any way

Tags: server-side-rendering, blazor-server-side

I have this code (and other not shown codes) in my Base Layout .razor page in Blazor server:

```
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
     {
         await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
        
         if (firstRender)
         {
             string language = await jsInterop.GetProperty("Language");
             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(language))
             {
                 await jsInterop.SetProperty("Language", "en");   
                 cultureChanger.ChangeCulture("en");             
             }
             else
             {
                 cultureChanger.ChangeCulture(language);                 
             }             
             GetLanguageValues();
       }
    }

string lang = "";
string direction = "";
private async Task GetLanguageValues()
{
    lang = textService.GetText(cultureChanger.Current, "lang");    
    direction = textService.GetText(cultureChanger.Current, "Direction");    
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Then I use lang and direction in wrappers of site ans stylesheet paths (in a HeadContent element). and I have other codes in OnAfterRender and their dependent methods in this BaseLayour.razor file.

These work in .Net 7 and below and also when I enable Interactivity in .Net 8, But I want to use a new .net 8 feature, Static Server rendering (ssr) mode in this blazor server site.

So I should not enable Interactivity in this layout because since this is a base layout the entire site becomes interactive.

Someone recommended to move the interactive parts to a separate component and make the component interactive. But since that component should contain @Body this recommendation is not working. Also if I want to Make the final part of the markup:

```
<div class="content px-4 mt-2">
    <CascadingValue Name="HttpContext" Value="httpContext.HttpContext" TValue="HttpContext">
        <CascadingValue Name="BaseLayout" Value="this" TValue="BaseLayout">
            @Body
        </CascadingValue>
    </CascadingValue>
</div>
```

a RenderFragment and pass it to the interactive component Blazor server throws an error. because I sending an arbitrary html to an interactive component and it is not allowed.

So because OnAfterRender is not working in an static rendering page, I need a lifecycle method to put my javascript interop codes in it.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can't, the way its designed now. As it seems someone else mentioned, significant re-architecting is in store if you want to achieve what you want with SSR. What comes to mind is, indeed, either islanding the javascript invocation or moving it to raw javascript itself which may (or may not) trigger a page refresh to then load the page in the actual culture's context. Finally, storing that in local or session storage.